# Oracle calculate the Median from a column containing values of type Date

Tags: oracle, median

I had the requirement to calculate the median value of a column, which of datatype date.

Comment: you mean a function like avg?

Answer (score 3):

As simple as selecting the median...

```
select median(a) from (
  select date '2010-01-01' a from dual union all
  select date '2010-01-02' a from dual union all
  select date '2010-01-05' a from dual
)
```

... which yields

```
2010-01-02
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MEDIAN()` function.

[Documentation Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions086.htm)